# Typescript + Reactjs - Imported svg does not render

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I was migrating some of my React files over to `.tsx` files and had errors on my svg imports:

```
import logo from './logo.svg'; // [ts] cannot find module './logo.svg'
```

So, I changed it to:

```
const logo = require('./logo.svg') as string
```

which fixed up the transpiler errors.

I am rendering it using React Bootstrap's `Image` tag:

```
<Image src={logo} className="..." />
```

However, that image does not render at all. I have tried changing the type to `as any` but no cigar. Can anyone help me?

Comment: How are you rendering it? Are you attempting to render this as a react component (e.g. `<logo />`)? This would need to be rendered in an image tag, like `<img src={logo} />`

Comment: Also, to get the `import` statement to pass in TS, [see this page from the webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/#importing-other-assets)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I updated the post to explain how I'm rendering it.

Comment: Strange, that _should_ work, and typescript wouldn't have anything to do with the image not getting rendered. Maybe something else is the culprit? Like the styles of a parent component, or an adjacent one. What do you get when you `console.log(logo)`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make sure you have the file `images.d.ts` in your root folder (next to `tsconfig.json`, etc) with the following contents:

```
declare module '*.svg'
declare module '*.png'
declare module '*.jpg'
```

Comment: may I ask what does "declare module '*.svg'" do?

Comment: Thank you for this, I was trying t use `React-SVGR` with typescript and I needed to add this for it to work. Check out this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/discussions/7910#discussioncomment-8235687) for more reference

Comment: checkout the [following stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75124839/6908282) which has a better approach for using `react-svgr`