# Getting NextJS Image Component & @svgr/webpack to play nicely together

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js, nextjs-image

I have a Next.js site with the `@svgr/webpack` library installed.  I have configured `next.config.js` to work with `@svgr/webpack` and now want to import an svg image and use it with the new `next/image` component.

Here is how I set up my `next.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ["images.vexels.com"],
  },
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: ["@svgr/webpack"],
    });

    return config;
  },
};
```

And here is what I am trying to do:

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import Logo from '@/svg/logo.svg'

<Image src={Logo} width={174} height={84} />
```

However, when I do that I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: src.startsWith is not a function

Source
client\image.tsx (278:13) @ Image

  276 | let isLazy =
  277 |   !priority && (loading === 'lazy' || typeof loading === 'undefined')
> 278 | if (src && src.startsWith('data:')) {
      |           ^
  279 |   // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs
  280 |   unoptimized = true
  281 |   isLazy = false
```

I thought that perhaps I should include the Logo component as an actual component, like this: `<Image src={<Logo />} width={174} height={84} />`

However, that also did not work.

Any idea what is wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 9):

With your current webpack config importing `@/svg/logo.svg` will only import the SVG file as a React component.

To [import it as a data URL](https://github.com/gregberge/svgr/tree/main/packages/webpack#using-with-url-loader-or-file-loader), you will need the following webpack config in your `next.config.js`.

```js
module.exports = {
    images: {
        domains: ['images.vexels.com']
    },
    webpack(config) {
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.svg$/,
            use: ['@svgr/webpack', 'url-loader']
        });

        return config;
    }
};
```

You'll then be able to use it in both ways: as a URL or as a component.

```js
import Image from 'next/image'
import svgUrl, { ReactComponent as Logo } from '@/svg/logo.svg'

<Image src={svgUrl} width={174} height={84} />
// or as a component
<Logo />
```

Comment: Thanks.  I am wondering, are there any downsides to importing it as a data URL?

Comment: If you really want to use `next/image` there's not much of a choice, you have to use a URL.

Comment: In some cases I have the option of putting the svg file in the public folder and calling it regular -- i.e., `src="/img/logo.svg`.  That is not always the case. But when it is the case, I am wondering are there any downsides to using a data URL?

Comment: Just that it seems unnecessary if you can just reference the URL to the SVG file. Keep in mind that if you do load the SVG via `@svgr/webpack` it will be part of the resulting webpack bundle, while referencing it directly from the public folder via URL won't.

Comment: note that if you're using typescript, then you need add either a `svg.d.ts` or `images.d.ts` file for the `import svgUrl, { ReactComponent as Logo } from '@/svg/logo.svg'` to work properly. Check out this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/discussions/7910#discussioncomment-8235687) and [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51257088/6908282) for more details

Comment: Note that `url-loader` is not recommended anymore since webpack5 - reference: https://react-svgr.com/docs/webpack/#use-with-url-loader-or-file-loader

Comment: [another answer by Loki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75124839/6908282) is a better approach since it doesn't use url-loader

Answer (score 4):

Other answers sacrifice the default width + height importing behavior provided by NextJS. My answer below retains this behaviour so that you don't need to manually check the dimensions of the file

### Desired usage

```js
import MySVG from "./mySVG.svg?svgr"; // SVGR loader

<MySVG />

import Image from "next/image";
import mySVG from "./mySVG.svg"; // Default NextJS loader

<Image src={mySVG} alt="" /> // (width and height will be applied automatically)
```

### Required next.config.js

```js
webpack(config, { dev: isDev, isServer }) {

    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/i,
      issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
      resourceQuery: /svgr/, // only use svgr to load svg if path ends with *.svg?svgr
      use: ["@svgr/webpack"],
    });

    // Re-add default nextjs loader for svg
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/i,
      loader: "next-image-loader",
      issuer: { not: /\.(css|scss|sass)$/ },
      dependency: { not: ["url"] },
      resourceQuery: { not: [/svgr/] }, // Ignore this rule if the path ends with *.svg?svgr
      options: { isServer, isDev, basePath: "", assetPrefix: "" },
    });

}
```

### Required typescript declaration (if using ts)

```
declare module "*.svg?svgr";
```

##### How I figured it out

1. Read these docs: https://react-svgr.com/docs/webpack/
2. Used this snippet to get the default rule applying to svgs

```js
webpack(config) {
    const defaultSvgLoader = config.module.rules.find(
      (rule) => typeof rule?.test?.test === "function" && rule.test.test(".svg")
    );
    console.log(defaultSvgLoader);
}
```

3. Added `resourceQuery: { not: [/svgr/] }` into the logged output object so that `*.svg?svgr` paths will be ignored

Comment: This is the best method I found - since it allow using svg both as a component and also as `Image src=...` Also it does not use `url-loader` which is [not recommended](https://react-svgr.com/docs/webpack/#use-with-url-loader-or-file-loader) anymore since webpack5

Comment: One issue is see with this approach is it creates a new file in `static/media` folder when `next/image` is used

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to previous answers, but the only way that worked for me to allow for both url-only imports as well as React component imports:

```
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
  webpack(config) {
    // Grab the existing rule that handles SVG imports
    const fileLoaderRule = config.module.rules.find(
      (rule) => rule.test && rule.test.test?.(".svg")
    );

    config.module.rules.push({
      oneOf: [
        // Reapply the existing rule, but only for svg imports ending in ?url
        {
          ...fileLoaderRule,
          test: /\.svg$/i,
          resourceQuery: /url/, // *.svg?url
        },
        // Convert all other *.svg imports to React components
        {
          test: /\.svg$/i,
          issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
          resourceQuery: { not: /url/ }, // exclude if *.svg?url
          use: ["@svgr/webpack"],
        },
      ],
    });

    // Modify the file loader rule to ignore *.svg, since we have it handled now.
    fileLoaderRule.exclude = /\.svg$/i;

    return config;
  },

  // ...other config
};
```

#### TypeScript declaration (if needed)

```
// svg.d.ts

/** svg imports with a ?url suffix can be used as the src value in Image components */
declare module "*.svg?url" {
  import { StaticImport } from "next/image";

  const defaultExport: StaticImport | string;
  export default defaultExport;
}
```

#### Sample usage

```
import Image from "next/image";
import Icon from "./my-icon.svg";
import iconUrl from "./my-icon.svg?url"

// ...

<Image src={iconUrl} />
<Icon />
```

Answer (score 1):

A workaround for this maybe by having a specific pattern for `svg` file name, and then configuring the default loader to ignore this pattern and `svgr/webpack` to load matches for this pattern

```
 webpack(config) {
    const fileLoaderRule = config.module.rules.find(
      (rule) => rule.test && rule.test.test(".svg")
    );
    fileLoaderRule.exclude = /\.icon\.svg$/;
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.icon\.svg$/,
      loader: require.resolve("@svgr/webpack"),
    });
    return config;
  },
```

here i'm using the pattern `*.icon.svg`, so any svg image that ends with it can be used like this

```
import Logo from "whatever/logo.icon.svg

const Whatever = () => <Logo />
```

and for other icons this'll work

```
import Image from "next/image";
import Logo from "whatever/logo.svg"

const Whatever = () => <Image src={Logo} alt="logo" width={100} height={100}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also working on it and just want to share my solution and touch all nuances.
I am using NextJS (new App router) with tailwind CSS.
I have next.config.mjs that I grabbed from the answers above.

```
// next.config.mjs
const nextConfig = {
  webpack(config) {
    // Grab the existing rule that handles SVG imports
    const fileLoaderRule = config.module.rules.find((rule) =>
      rule.test?.test?.(".svg")
    );
    config.module.rules.push({
      oneOf: [
        // Reapply the existing rule, but only for svg imports ending in ?url
        {
          ...fileLoaderRule,
          test: /\.svg$/i,
          resourceQuery: /url/, // *.svg?url
        },
        // Convert all other *.svg imports to React components
        {
          test: /\.svg$/i,
          issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
          resourceQuery: { not: /url/ }, // exclude if *.svg?url
          use: ["@svgr/webpack"],
        },
      ],
    });
    // Modify the file loader rule to ignore *.svg, since we have it handled now.
    fileLoaderRule.exclude = /\.svg$/i;
    return config;
  },
};

export default nextConfig;
```

I have the following folders structure:
src
--app
--components
--assets
----images (png, gif, jpeg ...)
------images.d.ts
----icons (svg)
------svg.d.ts

```
// svg.d.ts
    declare module "*.svg" {
      const content: React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGAttributes<SVGElement>>;
      export default content;
    }
    
    /** svg imports with a ?url suffix can be used as the src value in Image components */
    
        declare module "*.svg?url" {
          import type { StaticImport } from "next/image";
        
          const defaultExport: StaticImport | string;
          export default defaultExport;
        }
```

```
// images.d.ts
declare module '*.png';
declare module '*.jpg';
declare module '*.jpeg';
declare module '*.gif';
declare module '*.bmp';
declare module '*.tiff';
declare module '*.webp';
```

You do not need to import svg.d.ts inside tsconfig.json. And inside my tsx component I can import my `logo.svg` as  React Component or URL (to paste this URL into Next/image)

```
    import Logo from "assets/icons/logo.svg";
    import logo from "assets/icons/logo.svg?url";

    <Link href="/" className="flex-auto">
                {/* as data url */}
                <Image src={logo} width={155} height={28} alt="logotype" />
              </Link>
              {/* as component */}
              <Logo />
```

That is all. Good luck.