# How to use SVG in NextJS 13 with app directory?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I've decided to give a try to `app` directory and a lot of things got broken.
For example, the image import.
The pngs work just fine, but importing an SVG image makes it broken in `/app`.

For example, this particular URL works just fin with `/pages` and doesn't work with `/app`:

```
import Logo from 'public/company.svg';
```

The imported image object(from inside the component) looks as follows in console:

```
{
  src: '/_next/static/media/company.99a082b8.svg',
  height: 32,
  width: 162
}
```

The file itself is absent in `/media` folder.

How can I import the SVG image into NextJS 13+ project?

**Update:**

I've added SVGR to import SVGs as components and everything works normally, however it doesn't fix the build issue.

Comment: In my case, adding @svgr/webpack and changing next.config.js is working fine both in dev server and production server. I didn't deploy the project, but running "next build" and "next start" is working fine as in "next dev"

Comment: @anurag-dhamala sure, it works fine for me as well, but I wasn't going to use them as components, but as `src`. Anyway, it serves the purpose so I'll go with that solution. Thank you.

Comment: Check out the answer below. Turns out that we need to use Image from next/image. Thanks

Comment: You can use `@svgr/webpack` to import the SVG as a data URL too. See [Getting NextJS Image Component & @svgr/webpack to play nicely together](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66768451/1870780).

Comment: I am not sure if anyone could relate to that but after configuring "svgr/webpack" i still had errors that loader is not configured. I couldn't import inline svg and I was really confused. Finally it appeared that I had 'use client' missing at the top of file which solve the issue.

Answer (score 4):

@svgr/webpack solves the issue, but to use svg images as src we've to use Image from next/image as below. `<img/>` tag didn't work.

```js
import Image from "next/image";
import SVGIMG from "../public/vercel.svg";

export default function Page() {
    return (
       <Image src={SVGIMG} alt={""}/>
    )
}
```

Works in **next dev** and **next build && next start** !

Comment: It doesn't really help with the src, I've used both next/image and next/legacy/image.

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for. Bye, @svgr/webpack, embrace Turbopack

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with currentColor? Even if I manually edit the fills in my SVG file to be currentColor I can’t get SVGs included through next/image to use the parent’s color

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SVGR Playground](https://react-svgr.com/playground/) to convert the svg to a React Component. This way you can import it and use it like any other React Component. And if you want to change the color of the svg you can change the fill in the svg component to `currentColor` and remove the rest of the fill attributes, then you can style it using style or for example using tailwind. You can also change the dimensions of the svg by passing `width` and `height` through props but sometimes it doesn't scale the svg as it should or it doesn't scale it at all.

Answer (score -2):

//Simply create a component and place the svg code inside return
and remove xml, style and fill attributes from svg.

```
let InstaIcon = () => {
  return (
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 90 90">
      <path
        id="Path_947"
        d="M5.06,44.96c0-7.72-0.1-15.44,0.04-23.15c0.11-5.04,2.51-9.76,6.53-12.82
    C14.68,6.41,18.56,5,22.56,5.02c15.09,0,30.18-0.08,45.27,0.06c6.21,0.02,11.91,3.45,14.84,8.94c1.6,2.73,2.41,5.85,2.33,9.01
    c0,14.67-0.07,29.3,0,43.96c0.03,8.56-5.97,15.95-14.35,17.69c-1.29,0.24-2.6,0.34-3.91,0.31c-14.49,0-28.99-0.05-43.49,0.04
    c-8.63,0.1-16.13-5.89-17.92-14.33C5.08,69.35,4.97,67.98,5,66.61c0-7.22,0-14.43,0-21.65H5.06 M44.94,70.86
    c14.29,0.03,25.91-11.52,25.94-25.82c0.03-14.29-11.53-25.91-25.82-25.94S19.15,30.63,19.12,44.92c0,0.07,0,0.14,0,0.21
    C19.22,59.34,30.74,70.81,44.94,70.86 M76.9,18.33c0.07-2.95-2.27-5.39-5.21-5.45c-0.07,0-0.14,0-0.21,0
    c-3-0.03-5.46,2.38-5.49,5.38c0,0.05,0,0.09,0,0.14c0.08,2.97,2.48,5.36,5.46,5.41C74.46,23.79,76.9,21.34,76.9,18.33 M44.97,59.66
    c-8.1-0.03-14.65-6.62-14.62-14.72s6.62-14.65,14.72-14.62s14.64,6.61,14.62,14.7C59.64,53.11,53.07,59.64,44.97,59.66"
      />
    </svg>
  );
};

export default InstaIcon;
```